# Thunderbird Extensions. How do I set message composer body?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mozilla, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am currently developing an extension which needs to encrypt the body of the email you are writing. I already did the encryption part, but now I need to display a html in the message composer window. I already know how to extract the text with:

```
var msgComposer = window.gMsgCompose;
var editor = msgComposer.editor;
var text = editor.outputToString('text/plain', editor.eNone);
```

I haven't found a way to set the mail body however... Also Thunderbird API appears to have no documentation. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation available for Thunderbird's WebExtensions APIs, at:

https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

If you are still trying to solve this issue, you should probably look at the [`compose` API](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compose.html), in particular [`compose.setComposeDetails()`](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compose.html#setcomposedetails-tabid-details), or at [`composeScripts`](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/composeScripts.html). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64988866/3716552).