# Thunderbird78+: How to check for message create, reply and forward

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, thunderbird-webextensions

I am a beginner in thunderbird addons so I really appreciate if you can help me. I am trying to find a way in my background javascript to check whenever a user has opened the window for create a new message, reply a message and forward a message. I want to put a default text in the message window before the user is gonna send it. I know thunderbird 78+ should only uses web extension APIs and i found this *Compose API* but how to use it in my background script.

https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/78/compose.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [`setComposeDetails()`](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compose.html#setcomposedetails-tabid-details) is what you want.

> `setComposeDetails(tabId, details)`
>
> Updates the compose window. Specify only fields that you want to change. Currently only the to/cc/bcc/replyTo/followupTo/newsgroups fields and the subject are implemented.
>
> - `tabId` (integer)
> - `details` (ComposeDetails)

I have note tried it, but I suppose that either `details.body` or `details.plainTextBody` from the [`ComposeDetails`](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compose.html#compose-composedetails) object can be used to pass the default text you want to use. So I would try something like this in the background script:

```js
let details = {
    body: "This is my default text",
};
browser.messages.setComposeDetails(tabId, details);
```

You might have to combine it with a call to `messages.getComposeDetails()` if empty fields in `details` reset the values in the composer window (I don't know).

If you want to call this when the user opens a new compose window, I would look at the `window.onCreated` event. If you want to do it right before the message is sent instead, you should look at the `compose.onBeforeSend` event. All of them are described in the API documentation.